# How to useMemo with axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I avoid re-hitting to API after returning response from the same API under that same parameter

How can I use useMemo hook with axios part for better performance as I am new in react and did studied that useMemo can be used for performance optimization.

Edited:

the code with memo function now it this a right way?

```
 const initialState = {
      SwichManagment: [],
      Error: false
  }

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
          case "FETCHREQUEST":
              return {
                  ...state,
                  hasError: false
              };
          case "FETCHSUCCESS":
              return {
                  ...state,
                  SwichManagment: action.payload,
              };
          case "FETCHFAILURE":
              return {
                  hasError: true
              };
          default:
              return state;
      }
  }
  const SwitchManagment = ({ IdentifierId  }) => {

  const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

const memo = (callback) => {
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    const selector = JSON.stringify(args);
    if (cache.has(selector)) return cache.get(selector);
    const value = callback(...args);
    cache.set(selector, value);
    return value;
  };
};

const memoizedAxiosGet = memo(axios.get);  

      useEffect(() => {
          dispatch({
              type: "FETCHREQUEST"
          });
          memoizedAxiosGet(`https://example.com/${IdentifierId}/now`)
              .then(reponse => {
                  dispatch({
                      type: "FETCHSUCCESS",
                      payload: response.data
                  });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  dispatch({
                      type: "FETCHFAILURE"
                  });
              });
      }, [IdentifierId]);

      return (
        <div >
        {Object.keys(states.SwitchManagment).map(key => (
          <div className="item" key={states.SwitchManagment[key].id}>
            <p>{states.SwitchManagment[key].name}</p>
            <p>
                {states.SwitchManagment[key].progress}
           </p>
         </div>
        ))}
    </div>
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`React.useMemo` does not save values from previous results. Check [this example at dev.to](https://dev.to/kennethlum/the-usememo-hook-in-reactjs-has-a-short-memory-2a5m):

```js
  const value = useMemo(() => expensiveFunction(a), [a]);
```

> When it already did the calculation for `a` being `2`, then it won't do
> it for `2` next time. Likewise for the `3` or `4`.
>
> However, it really can only memoize one value. If the first time, it
> did the calculation for `1`, and next it did the calculation for `2`, it
> won't remember what the result is for `1` any more. When supplied with `1`
> again, it will do the calculation again.

So in your case, you should create a `memo` function with long memory:

```js
const memo = (callback) => {
  // We will save the key-value pairs in the following variable. It will be our cache storage
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    // The key will be used to identify the different arguments combination. Same arguments means same key
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);
    // If the cache storage has the key we are looking for, return the previously stored value
    if (cache.has(key)) return cache.get(key);
    // If the key is new, call the function (in your case axios.get)
    const value = callback(...args);
    // And save the new key-value pair to the cache
    cache.set(key, value);
    return value;
  };
};

const memoizedAxiosGet = memo(axios.get);
```

This `memo` function will act like a key-value cache. If the params (in your case your URL) of your function (`axios.get`) are the same, the function will not be executed. Instead, the previous result will be returned.

So you can just use this memoized version `memoizedAxiosGet` in your `useEffect` to make sure network request are not repeated for that particular petition.

**[Check this demo integrated in React!](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rain-snnb9?file=/src/App.js)**

Comment: Hi @Rashomon can you explain by adding comment how it works? because I am not getting the things as I am beginner in react

Comment: @puru Added more details, what problem do you have? :)

Comment: Actually @Rashomon I was just asking for comment for memo function that how its working i.e. logic behind the memo function..

Comment: @puru Updated with descriptions for `memo`

Comment: @puru Move the `memo` definition out of the component. Memo is always the same and doesnt change with renders, Only its internal cache will change and we need to keep it

Comment: Btw, dont edit your own question with the resolution. Create a demo in https://codesandbox.io/ or other external services. This way people will understand the problem in the future

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213027/discussion-between-puru-and-rashomon).

Comment: Hi @Rashomon here is codesandbox.io part in this memo is not working  in console.log part no resut https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-lovelace-vxlzn?file=/App.js ```'selector' is not defined```

Comment: Declare `memoizedAxiosGet` outside of the component too. I will create a demo

Comment: @puru Added a demo with pokemon. Check it out! :)

Comment: what happen if the request fail?

Comment: This implementation just saves the result of a function. If the function returns a promise, the promise (and its result) will be cached. We dont check if it fails or not. But its possible to implement your way :)